# Creating Materials for Second Life

Tags: mesh, materials

I have been creating materials on mesh objects for Second Life by selecting an area of vertices and assigning a new Material to it. When I export to Collada/DAE and upload to SL, each of the Material areas appears to have a line/shadow around it. I have also been using Separate by selection to divide larger mesh objects into smaller mesh objects, but I get the exact same outline/shadow between mesh objects. Is there some setting or procedure that is optimal for creating materials/objects for Second Life?

Here is a snapshot of how it looks in SL:

[image: Mesh Object in Second Life]

~Sean

Adding a screenshot of my Blender setup.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My question was answered on the Second Life Forum: These shadows happen because of a setting during upload to Second Life/OpenSim. On the first screen of SL/OS upload is a setting called "Generate Normals". Setting that to **on** causes the shadows. Setting that to **off** will not produce the shadows seen above.

Answer (score 0):

Sean, did the game provide the model with the UVs unwrapped or did you do it yourself? That might happen when the UV is not correctly unwrapped

Comment: The UV was already configured/unwrapped in the Blender file I got, and worked fine for the full, single material/uncut mesh object. It also appears to be fine in my  multi-material, cut up mesh. Although, I guess there could be issues that I am unaware of regarding the UV map in my version of the mesh. I'll do some testing with a 'test' map I have to determine if the UV map is correct for my multi materials/objects version.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the settings/how you set it up on blender?

Comment: I checked the UV mapping in the game with a special texture intended for that purpose. It lines up and appears to be perfect for all the materials and objects, but still has the shadows along the material/object edges like the other texture that was on it. I suppose there might be some UV mapping error where each material touches the next material, but I would not know how to test that.

Comment: Added a screenshot of my Blender setup above.